# Use an if statement to compare the entire column of one row to another data frame. in python

Tags: python, pandas

df1 has a latitude and longitude column at the gas station, and df2 has a latitude and longitude column at a nearby convenience store.

I want to know how many convenience stores in df2 are around in one gas station of df1.

If the distance between the gas station and the convenience store is less than 1 km, it outputs 1 or 0.

I want to compare one row of df1 to all the rows of df2 to see how many convenience stores are within a kilometer compared to one gas station in df1 and all the convenience stores in df2.

```
def dist(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
dist = haversine((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2))
dist = int(dist)
if dist <= 1:
    return 1
else:
    return 0

dist_columns=[]
for index, row in data1.iterrows():
    freq=[]
    for index, row2 in data2.iterrows():

        if dist(row['lat'],row['lon'],row2['lat'],row2['lon']) == 1:
            freq.append(1)
        else:
            freq.append(0)
    dist_columns.append(sum(freq))
```

Even if there are places within 1km, they can not grasp it.

example

input

```
print(df1) 
gas_station  lat   lon

    A              32   107
    B              33   108

print(df2)

store  lat  lon
 F     33   107
 U     33   120 
 I     34   100
```

output

```
gas station    lat  lon   count(store within a kilometer)
A              32   107    2
B              33   108    1
```

Comment: Please give input df example and expected output.

Comment: input 

df1 
gas_station  lat   lon
    A              32   107
    B              33   108

df2
store  lat  lon
 F       33  107
 U      33   120
 I        34   100


output
gas station  lat  lon   count(store within a kilometer)
    A              32   107    2
    B              33   108    1

Comment: Show some rows of the inout dataframe and output datarame